# Strip Newline Character from command line output in Ant

Tags: ant

I am writing an ant build script that does a sshexec and returns the output of the command ran into the outputproperty attribute.

The value of the outputproperty has a newline character on the end of them. Anyway I can strip that newline character from the output?

Regards,

Stephen

Comment: Hi Steve, could you post the relevant snippet of the script?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find the answer: The newline character represented by `&#10` can be used when using the `<equals>` command.

Regards,
Steve